# Creating A Custom Alert Pop Up Loads too slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a custom pop up alert. Adding it to my view and animating it all works well, however it takes a while to load upon triggering it.

This is how I have created the view.

```
@implementation SAActionAlertView

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title view:(UIView *)view;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ActionAlertView" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        self.actionAlertText.text = title;
        self.view = view;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)animate;
{
    [self.view addSubview:self];
    self.center = self.superview.center;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        __block CGRect queueFrame = self.frame;
        __block int queueY = queueFrame.origin.y;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            queueY += 50;
            self.frame = queueFrame;
            self.alpha = .3;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

And this is how I am presenting it on my main View Controller.

```
#pragma mark - Notification Center

-(void)trackQueued:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    SAActionAlertView *actionAlert = [[SAActionAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Track Queued" view:self.view];
       [actionAlert animate];
}
```

It takes far too long for the view to appear and animate. I want the pop up to be instant upon triggering the event. Any ideas on the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing the animation after a notification I am assuming you are not operating on the main thread. You should. If you perform UI changes on any thread other than the main thread you can not be sure when they are actually reflected by the actual screen on the device.

```
- (void) trackQueued:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SAActionAlertView *actionAlert = [[SAActionAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Track Queued" view:self.view];
        [actionAlert animate];
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to fix it. The first time the alert is shown on a view controller though it still lags before being presented. After the first time the pop up happens it is presented instantly though.

Comment: @Andy That might be due to iOS actually loading the nib when you create it for the first time... don't really now, have you tried adding NSLog statements to determine what call actually causes the delay?